# Confusing UNPIVOT

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table that shows currency exchange rates thusly

[image]

I want to unpivot it to the following layout

[image]

but when I use

```
SELECT CREATION_DATE, CURRENCY, RATE
FROM (
 SELECT CREATION_DATE, JMD, ISK, COP, USD, EGP, PAB
 FROM EXCHANGE_RATES) XR
 
 UNPIVOT(RATE FOR CURRENCY IN 
         JMD, ISK, COP, USD, EGP, PAB
        ) AS U;
```

I get an error on one of the currency codes

```
SQL compilation error: syntax error line 7 at position 9 unexpected 'JMD'. syntax error line 8 at position 10 unexpected 'AS'.
```

Even if I try

```
 SELECT * FROM EXCHANGE_RATES
    UNPIVOT(CURRENCY FOR MO (JMD, ISK, COP, USD, EGP, PAB))
```

I get an error on one of the currency codes:

```
SQL compilation error: The type of column 'COP' conflicts with the type of other columns in the UNPIVOT list.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So get the error:

> SQL compilation error: The type of column 'COP' conflicts with the type of other columns in the UNPIVOT list.

If I use the data like to looks how you have it:

aka:

```
with exchange_rates(creation_date, jmd, isk, cop, usd, egp, pab) as (
    select * from values
    ('2022-09-21 21:33:37.973'::timestamp_ntz, 153.3, 141.1, 4422.5, 1, 19.4, 1)
)
select * 
from exchange_rates
unpivot(rate for currency in (jmd, isk, cop, usd, egp, pab) )
```

reading the error message, and slowing down, it's complaining of types

```
with exchange_rates(creation_date, jmd, isk, cop, usd, egp, pab) as (
    select * from values
    ('2022-09-21 21:33:37.973'::timestamp_ntz, 153.3, 141.1, 4422.5, 1.0, 19.4, 1.0)
)
select *, system$typeof(jmd), system$typeof(cop), system$typeof(usd)
from exchange_rates
```

| CREATION_DATE | JMD | ISK | COP | USD | EGP | PAB | SYSTEM$TYPEOF(JMD) | SYSTEM$TYPEOF(COP) | SYSTEM$TYPEOF(USD) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-21 21:33:37.973 | 153.3 | 141.1 | 4,422.5 | 1 | 19.4 | 1 | NUMBER(4,1)[SB2] | NUMBER(5,1)[SB4] | NUMBER(1,0)[SB1] |

and the `1` will default to a different type to the `141.1`, to test, forcing it all to `::number(20,2)`

```
with exchange_rates(creation_date, jmd, isk, cop, usd, egp, pab) as (
    select * from values
    ('2022-09-21 21:33:37.973'::timestamp_ntz, 153.3::number(20,2), 141.1::number(20,2), 4422.5::number(20,2), 1.0::number(20,2), 19.4::number(20,2), 1.0::number(20,2))
)
select * 
from exchange_rates
unpivot(rate for currency in (jmd, isk, cop, usd, egp, pab) )
```

works:

| CREATION_DATE | CURRENCY | RATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-21 21:33:37.973 | JMD | 153.3 |
| 2022-09-21 21:33:37.973 | ISK | 141.1 |
| 2022-09-21 21:33:37.973 | COP | 4,422.5 |
| 2022-09-21 21:33:37.973 | USD | 1 |
| 2022-09-21 21:33:37.973 | EGP | 19.4 |
| 2022-09-21 21:33:37.973 | PAB | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose the currencies in brackets
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/unpivot.html#examples

```
SELECT CREATION_DATE, CURRENCY, RATE
FROM (
 SELECT CREATION_DATE, JMD, ISK, COP, USD, EGP, PAB
 FROM EXCHANGE_RATES) XR
 
 UNPIVOT(RATE FOR CURRENCY IN (
         JMD, ISK, COP, USD, EGP, PAB
        )) AS U;
```

Comment: I tried that too. Same issue. It errors out on one of the currencies

`SQL compilation error: The type of column 'COP' conflicts with the type of other columns in the UNPIVOT list`

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
WITH EXCHANGE_RATES(CREATION_DATE, JMD, ISK, COP) AS (
    SELECT  
  CREATION_DATE::TIMESTAMP_NTZ, JMD::NUMBER(19,6) AS JMD, ISK::NUMBER(19,6) AS ISK, COP::NUMBER(19,6) AS COP
  FROM  EXCHANGE_RATES
)
SELECT * 
FROM EXCHANGE_RATES
UNPIVOT(RATE FOR CURRENCY IN (JMD, ISK, COP) )
```

Thanks everyone for helping out!